# Regex For Log Parsing

Tags: regex, parsing, logging

I am trying to find all of the exceptions that are in a log that are not of type InvalidArgumentException. Our log writes out lines like the following:

```
Class:       InvalidArgumentException
```

The regex I am trying to use is:

```
/Class:.*(!InvalidArgument)Exception/
```

Essentially, start with the word `Class:`, allow any characters after class that are not equal to InvalidArgument, and then include the word `Exception`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possibility with negative look behind:

```
/^Class:.*?(?<!InvalidArgument)Exception/
```

test with `grep -P`:

```
kent$  echo "Class:   foo    InvalidArgumentException
Class: bar NullPointerException"|grep -P '^Class:.*?(?<!InvalidArgument)Exception'
Class: bar NullPointerException
```